# iOS Push Service App as an alternative to support Web Push Notification on iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Since iOS does not support Service Worker and Web Push Notification (as of Jun'17), is it possible to submit an iOS Push Service App (with only APNS function) to Apple (i.e. XXX Push Service) so that iOS user can opt to receive push notification of Web-app via APNS?